# Case expressions and aliases in jOOQ 3.5.3

Tags: java, jooq

I'm having a problem with expressing the following query in jOOQ

```html
SELECT s.season_name, l.league_name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.full_time_result = 'H' THEN 'H' END) AS home_wins,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.full_time_result = 'D' THEN 'D' END) AS draws,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN m.full_time_result = 'A' THEN 'A' END) AS away_wins,
  COUNT(m.full_time_result) AS all_matches
  FROM football_stats.matches AS m
  JOIN football_stats.seasons AS s USING (season_id)
  JOIN football_stats.leagues AS l USING (league_id) GROUP BY s.season_name, l.league_name
```

My java code for this is:

```js
final Field<String> homeWins = DSL.decode().when(MATCHES.FULL_TIME_RESULT.eq(HOME_WIN), HOME_WIN).as("home_wins");
final Field<String> draws = DSL.decode().when(MATCHES.FULL_TIME_RESULT.eq(DRAW), DRAW).as("draws");
final Field<String> awayWins = DSL.decode().when(MATCHES.FULL_TIME_RESULT.eq(AWAY_WIN), AWAY_WIN).as("away_wins");
final Field<?>[] fields = {SEASONS.SEASON_NAME, LEAGUES.LEAGUE_NAME, DSL.count(homeWins), DSL.count(draws), DSL.count(awayWins), DSL.count()};
final SelectQuery<Record> query = dslContext.selectQuery();
query.addSelect(fields);
query.addFrom(MATCHES);
query.addJoinOnKey(SEASONS, JoinType.JOIN, Keys.MATCHES__FK_MATCHES_SEASONS);
query.addJoinOnKey(LEAGUES, JoinType.JOIN, Keys.MATCHES__FK_MATCHES_LEAGUES);
query.addGroupBy(SEASONS.SEASON_NAME,LEAGUES.LEAGUE_NAME);
final Record result = query.fetchOne();
```

And the query generated by jOOQ is:

```html
select 
  "football_stats"."seasons"."season_name", 
  "football_stats"."leagues"."league_name", 
  count("home_wins"), 
  count("draws"), 
  count("away_wins"), 
  count(*)
from "football_stats"."matches"
  join "football_stats"."seasons"
  on "football_stats"."matches"."season_id" = "football_stats"."seasons"."season_id"
  join "football_stats"."leagues"
  on "football_stats"."matches"."league_id" = "football_stats"."leagues"."league_id"
group by 
  "football_stats"."seasons"."season_name", 
  "football_stats"."leagues"."league_name"
```

it results in

```html
ERROR: column "home_wins" does not exist
```

However, when I omit `.as("alias_name")`, then jOOQ generates

```html
select 
  "football_stats"."seasons"."season_name", 
  "football_stats"."leagues"."league_name", 
  count(case when "football_stats"."matches"."full_time_result" = 'H' then 'H' end), 
  count(case when "football_stats"."matches"."full_time_result" = 'D' then 'D' end), 
  count(case when "football_stats"."matches"."full_time_result" = 'A' then 'A' end), 
  count(*)
from "football_stats"."matches"
  join "football_stats"."seasons"
  on "football_stats"."matches"."season_id" = "football_stats"."seasons"."season_id"
  join "football_stats"."leagues"
  on "football_stats"."matches"."league_id" = "football_stats"."leagues"."league_id"
group by 
  "football_stats"."seasons"."season_name", 
  "football_stats"."leagues"."league_name"
```

How can I make jOOQ to generate it like `count(case when "football_stats"."matches"."full_time_result" = 'A' then 'A' end) as 'away_wins'`?

Also, can I make it generate `USING` instead of `ON` (`addJoinUsing` method also generates `ON`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aliased the wrong expression

#### In SQL, you wrote:

```sql
COUNT(CASE WHEN m.full_time_result = 'H' THEN 'H' END) AS home_wins
```

#### With jOOQ, you wrote:

```java
homeWins = decode().when(MATCHES.FULL_TIME_RESULT.eq(HOME_WIN), HOME_WIN).as("home_wins");
```

and then:

```java
DSL.count(homeWins);
```

So, jOOQ generated exactly the SQL you wrote.

#### You intended, however, to write this:

```java
homeWins = decode().when(MATCHES.FULL_TIME_RESULT.eq(HOME_WIN), HOME_WIN);
```

and then:

```java
DSL.count(homeWins).as("home_wins");
```

#### Side-note:

In the upcoming jOOQ 3.6, you will be able to simplify your `COUNT(CASE...)` expression by using the [SQL standard `FILTER` clause on aggregate functions](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/30/the-awesome-postgresql-9-4-sql2003-filter-clause-for-aggregate-functions/):

```
DSL.count().filterWhere(MATCHES.FULL_TIME_RESULT.eq(HOME_WIN)).as("home_wins")
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Everything works as I wanted after I used alias correctly.

Comment: @Dzieciak: Sure, anytime. Great to hear it works now!